Next-auth redirect to localhost in my login page
Im deploying my Nextjs 14 app in AWS EC2 using AWS CLI, Docker, Github.
For authentication i use next-auth. Every time user gets access sucessfully next-auth redirects them to localhost.
.env

Dockerfile:
FROM node:21 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --force 


COPY . .


RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm","run", "start"]

signIn action:
    signIn('credentials', {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
          callbackUrl: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}`
        })

auth.ts:
    import NextAuth, { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
    import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
    
    export const authOptions: NextAuthConfig = {
      providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
          async authorize(credentials, req) {
            if (!credentials.email || !credentials.password) return null
            const { email, password } = credentials
            console.log(credentials, 'credentials')
            try {
              const response = await fetch(
                'http://**********:6060/auth/signin',
                {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
                }
              )
              const data = await response.json()
              return data
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err)
              return null
            }
          }
        })
      ],
      session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
      },
      trustHost: true,
      secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
      callbacks: {
        jwt({ token, user }) {
          if (user) {
            return { ...token, ...user }
          }
          return token
        },
        session: ({ token, session }) => {
          session.user = token.user
          session.token = token.token
          return session
        },
        authorized({ auth }: { auth: any }) {
          return !!auth?.user // this ensures there is a logged in user for -every- request
        }
      },
      pages: {
        signIn: '/sign-in' // overrides the next-auth default signin page https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/pages
      }
    }
    
    export const {
      handlers: { GET, POST },
      auth
    } = NextAuth(authOptions)

I get this error:

The NEXTAUTH_URL variable is available in the container logs but not in the browser. Please refer to the container logs for more information



Thanks for helping!

Do you have .dockerignore file?

No. I haven´t one. Answer is below

My solution was: Install next-auth v5 beta16

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I had the exact problem before!
SHORT ANSWER
Skipping the basics
You've got to set AUTH_URL environment variable in your Dockerfile like that
ENV AUTH_URL=https://www.yourdomain.com/api/auth

LONG ANSWER
Only read this one if the short answer did not work for you. Make sure you follow my guide step by step carefully.
How to implement Next Auth v.5 for external API login in Next js 14 and app router

The error message The NEXTAUTH_URL variable is available in the container logs but not in the browser indicates that the NEXTAUTH_URL is being set correctly within the Docker container, but it's not being passed correctly to the Next.js application running inside the container.
First update the docker file : ENV NEXTAUTH_URL=<YOUR_NEXTAUTH_URL>
Update deployment process then :
docker run -e NEXTAUTH_URL=<YOUR_NEXTAUTH_URL> -p 80:80 your-image-name
Now you can verify by printing the NEXTAUTH_URL
then might be error resolve.

I have the same issue. I added the AUTH_URL to the AWS environment settings, but the logs say it's undefined. AWS environment does not read the AUTH_URL.
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.19",

If you want to have an environment variable available in the browser from a nextjs backend you must prefix with NEXT_PUBLIC_. See Bundling Environment Variables for the Browser.

Does next-auth require env variables available for the brower to redirect?
